# what is the recurrence that describe this run time algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations

[image]
Is the recurrence that describe this run time algorithm  is $T(n) = 2(T/2) + n$? Am I correct? and is the base case for this question $T(1) = 1$? What if happens if it is $T(3)$ how do I get the answer?

Comment: How do you get your answer?

Comment: It should be $$\begin{align}T(n)&=T(n-1)+n-1\qquad T(1)=0\\&=\frac12n(n-1)\end{align}$$in which case every possible pair of $(i,j)$ with $i\lt j$ is selected and compared.

Comment: How did you obtain $T/2$? $T$ is a function, and, as far as I am aware, it must be assigned an input. Where is that in the fraction?

Comment: Aside from the general phrase divide and conquer, you did not describe the algorithm.  Presumably you are splitting the array into two equal pieces, checking each piece, and checking between the pieces somehow.  You should describe what you check between the pieces, as that figures into the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

It should be $T(n) = T(n-1)+n-1,$ $T(1)=1$. For in each subproblem of size $n$, we have a subproblem of size $n-1$ (comparing the numbers $A[1],\ldots A[n-1]$ and linear work ($n-1$ comparisons between elements). It follows that $T(n) = \frac12 (n-1)n + 1$. For clearly $T(1) = \frac12(1-1)\cdot 1+1=1$ and if $T(n) = \frac12 (n-1)n + 1$ for some positive integer $n$, then
\begin{align}
T(n+1) &= T(n)+n-1\\ &=\frac12(n-1)n + 1 + n\\ &= \frac12 n(n+1) +1,
\end{align}
so by induction the statement holds for all positive integers $n$.

Comment: OP did not describe the algorithm except to say divide and conquer.  This is one approach, but the $2T(n/2)$ suggests that OP is splitting the array in half, not splitting off one element.

Comment: How does this run time recurrences T(n) = T(n-1) + n satisfy the above condition? it is A[i] = A[j] with i < j, am I right? so if i is 2 j is 3 then A[2] must be same as A[3] but if you substitute A[2] = T(2) = T(2-1) + 2 = 3 and T(3) = T(3-1) + 3 = 6 how does T(2) and T(3) equal??

Comment: @TheCodeLearner I have corrected my answer. Please see the edit.

Comment: @Math1000 but how does T(n) = T(n-1) + n - 1 satisfy A[i] = A[j]? for example, T(2) = T(2-1) + 2-1 => T(1) + 1 = 2 , T(3) = T(3-1) + 3-1 => T(2) + 2 = 4 . Therefore, T(2) != T(3). so how does it satisfy A[i] = A[j]?